# Не могу понять как реализовать элемент страницы(сетка)

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Прошу помочь советом как правильно реализовать этот элемент верстки? Может есть какие-то удобные JS плагины или типо того? Попробовал Masonry, как-то не особо помогло, ну или может я не понял как правильно сделать. В любом случае прошу помочь советом.

[image: Проблема с реализацией сетки]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите на эту верстку как на три колонки. Можно сверстать любым способом, флексбокс на коленке по [ссылке](https://codepen.io/kerlon5/pen/dyMZYpV)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="one"/>
    <div class="two"/>
    <div class="three"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!